# SQL: Database structure

Tags: sql, database, database-normalization

I have a little blackout.

In my database I have til now the following tables:

- `Courses: ID`
- `Students: ID`
- `CoursesStudents: CourseID, StudentID`

Now I have problems with connecting the marks with the students and courses.

The marks must be also connected with the school year. E. g.

- 1st year, 1st semester : 12 points
- 1st year, 2nd semester: 10 points
- 2nd year, 1st semester: 8 points
- 2nd year, 2nd semester: 5 points

I thought about

```
StudentsCoursesMarksYear: StudentID, CoursesID, Mark, Year
```

But I think it is not really right/the best...

Comment: I don't think the description of Courses and Students describes them correctly. Where is Mark/Year?

Comment: @Abhinav The Courses-table owns ID, Name & Description. The Students-table ID, FirstName, LastName, and so on ... In the CoursesStudents-table is an ID from a Student and an ID from a Course. Because a course can have some students ans a student can have some courses. Now I want a table or some tables who connect the student to the specific mark of a year+semester of a specific courses from him. Without the year/semester thing I could have used the "CoursesStudents"-table as "CoursesStudentsMark"-table.

Comment: Well then you are already on the right track. :) This is the level of normalization you should go for. If you change `CoursesStudents` to `CoursesStudents: CoursesStudentsID, CourseID, StudentID` and use that in `StudentsCoursesMarksYear` as `StudentsCoursesMarksYear: CoursesStudentsID, Mark, Year`; that would be acceptable too and rather more normalized. (Let me add, unnecessary normalization)

Comment: @Abhinav Thanks, that looks good! Well, it is nice to see people help beginners like me :-)

Answer (score 0):

You're close. But the year doesn't look sufficient; you need the semester, too.

```
StudentMarks: StudentID, CourseID, Mark, Year, Semester
```

Primary key is {StudentID, CourseID, Mark, Year, Semester}. Since it's all key, it's in BCNF at the very least.

In a real-world academic application, you'd almost certainly need several other tables. One, for example, might have to do with which years and semesters a particular course is offered. (Some of my courses were offered only in even-numbered years.)

Answer (score 0):

You can add `Year`, `Semester` and `Mark` to `CoursesStudents` table, because if you add another table this tables is useless